# Problem sending messages at regular intervals for Discord.js

Tags: node.js, discord.js, intervals, sendmessage

My goal is to create a Discord.js bot to automate sending a message at an interval. But when I run my program, the bot starts fine and connects to Discord but when it needs to send the message according to the given time, the bot disconnects and shows this error message :

**channel.send("test");
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'send').**

Here is my code :

```
const Discord = require('discord.js')
const client = new Discord.Client({ intents: ["GUILD_MESSAGES"] });
const { Client, Intents } = require('discord.js');

client.on('ready', () => {
  var testChannel = client.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.id === 'ID_CHANNEL');

  console.log("I'm connected !");

  setInterval(() => {
    testChannel.send("test");
  }, 5000);
});

client.login('TOKEN')
```

Thank you in advance for your precious help,

Comment: who says you found a channel ? i think you should check: `if (testChannel)` and then set interval , if `testChannel` is undefined -> do not set interval

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it doesn't work, do you have another method to replace "testChannel" ?

Comment: i don't understand what is not working ? what is the value of `testChannel` ?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be lack of some intents. If you provide intents manually bot will not get anything but things that you have included in your client configuration, so `testchannel` will always be `undefined`. So you can solve this easily, by adding intents.

```
const Discord = require('discord.js')
const { Client, Intents } = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MEMBERS, Intents.FLAGS.DIRECT_MESSAGES, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES] });

client.on('ready', () => {
  var testChannel = client.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.id === 'ID_CHANNEL');

  console.log("I'm connected !");

  setInterval(() => {
    testChannel.send("test");
  }, 5000);
});

client.login('TOKEN')
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but after I added the intentions line it gave me this error : ReferenceError: Cannot access 'Intents' before initialization

Comment: Change the position of the line with intents like I did, in your example they're below the place where you use the intents, they should be declared above the place where you use them, thats what error says. So it should look like in my version.

Comment: In fact, all that you need to do is replace your first 3 lines with mine first 3 lines, and that will do.

Comment: That's what I did and now I get the error : [Symbol(code)]: 'DISALLOWED_INTENTS'

Comment: Now you need to go to Discord Dev. page, open your bot, go to bot page and enable SERVER MEMBERS INTENT and MESSAGE CONTENT INTENT. If your bot is in 75 servers or more you need to apply for verification and intents and you'll need to contact discord staff about further help.

Comment: Thank you very much, the program works !